# How do I not display a GlyphRenderer table when plotting bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer in the bokeh documentation.  I want to be able to plot a bokeh plot without the long GlyphRenderer list displaying.

I have tried saving the p.hexbin line to a variable called 'test'.  However, this new 'test' variable is being saved as a tuple and can no longer be used with the 'show()' function to display a bokeh plot.  The example code I am using here is straight from the bokeh documentation [site](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.hexbin).

```py
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x = 2 + 2*np.random.standard_normal(500)
y = 2 + 2*np.random.standard_normal(500)

p = figure(match_aspect=True, tools="wheel_zoom,reset")
p.background_fill_color = '#440154'
p.grid.visible = False

p.hexbin(x, y, size=0.5, hover_color="pink", hover_alpha=0.8)

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("count", "@c"), ("(q,r)", "(@q, @r)")])
p.add_tools(hover)

show(p)
```

I only want the hexbin plot to display when I run the code, not the Glyph tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried saving the p.hexbin line to a variable called 'test'. However, this new 'test' variable is being saved as a tuple and can no longer be used with the 'show()' function to display a bokeh plot.

Printing outputs is standard Python behavior, there is nothing we can do about that. The function returns a list, so Python will print a list. The only thing to suppress that behavior, as you have noted, is to assign the output to a variable. However, since you don't care about its value, it can/should be ignored. There is no reason to pass it to `show`, you should continue to call show, *on `p`*, exactly the way you have been without any change:

```
rs = p.hexbin(x, y, size=0.5, hover_color="pink", hover_alpha=0.8)

show(p)
```